# Node-sass does not run on npm-start V6.0.0

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I have been trying to install node-sass using

`npm i node-sass`

but I am getting the following error whenever I try `npm start`:

```
Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.
```

I even tried downgrading to V5.0.0 or V4.14 for node-sass but it just won't install! It would get stuck at the end, and when I would force exit using `ctrl+c`, it outputs a huge log (please let me know if I can post it here).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same issue, I needed to check my node version by running `node -v` and compare to the [supported node-sass version](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)

Then I uninstall the node-sass with `npm uninstall node-sass` (I uninstall the @types/node-sass as well, check if you have devDependencies containing a reference to node-sass and remove it) and then reinstall again `npm i node-sass@4.14` it was 4.14 in my case because I have NodeJS v14.16.1 installed, I runned `npm i` to rebuild all the packages I had and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

## This fixes it

To install a working node-sass version, you can use

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.0
```

**Choose your version number** using the following table, according to the node version you are using, which you can check using the command `node --version`

[image: node-sass compatibility table]

**I hope this is helpful**

Answer (score 1):

That message is related to `sass-loader` that had a specific version range, that was expanded in https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v11.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after following the below steps.

1. run npm uninstall node-sass.
2. add the following dependencies to the package.json file.

   "node-sass" : "^6.0.0",
   "sass-loader" : "^11.1.1"
3. then run npm install.